# Getting Directions from player

Tags: unity, c#

I have a camera player in a scene. Scene contains a fixed north which i want to indicate on my compass with needle but how can i do it?
 I tried this code using a [tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urNuYkkbZCc) so far but its north is not right

```
   public void ChangeNortDirection() {

        northDirection.z = player.eulerAngles.y + 10;
        northLayer.localEulerAngles = northDirection;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: its 2D compass where needle is moving

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt an image updated.

Comment: Why is it that you add 10 to `player.eulerAngles.y`?

Comment: That was for testing ! you can omit it

Comment: Ok. Do you have a screen shot of the compass component properties in the inspector (and also it's parent)? Is the parent component rotation set correctly?

Comment: @hobnob actually i dont have access right now to the project. Player.eulerAngles is set to 0,0,0

Comment: generally do you think that its is right? northDirection.z = player.eulerAngles.y

Comment: My project has fixed north.

Comment: Assuming that the northDirection variable has 0 for X and Y properties, with only Z changing (no reason why not that I can see), then this looks fine to me. It would suggest something else odd, like the layer having the wrong parent, the parent being rotated incorrectly, or something else. My gut says this probably isn't a coding issue :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51240/discussion-between-mohammad-faizan-khan-and-hobnob).

Comment: I have serious concern on the codes because in a my scene, north is fixed. And my code is updating the north direction and setting its rotation to my niddle.

Comment: I've posted an update in the chat. Nothing conclusive (I can't replicate the problem), but I've posted all of my code and screenshots, so hopefully this will help you get to the bottom of the problem